# For Google App Engine, do I need Java EE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I am going to set up my development environment for Google App Engine (Java), but I'm not sure what download should I choose.

I can download:

- Java SE 6 Update 27
- JDK 6 Update 26 with Java EE

Do I need Java EE, or should I stick with the newer release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SE JDK is enough, unless you really need EE.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u27-download-440405.html (Java 6)

Comment: `Google App Engine supports Java 5 and Java 6. When your Java application is running on App Engine, it runs using the Java 6 virtual machine (JVM) and standard libraries. Ideally, you should use Java 6 for compiling and testing your application to ensure that the local server behaves similarly to App Engine.` - So Java 7 is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you actually cannot use full J2EE stack on Google App engine, so Java SE is more than enough :)

Answer (score 1):

As you are setting up your development environment, I recommend eclipse plugin for Google AppEgine.

[GAE Eclipse Plugin - Instructions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse.html)